# Is there a way to get request context within a decorator in Nest JS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am trying to build a decorator to "log" request info

```
export const Tracking = () => {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const method = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = async function(...args: any[]) {
      console.log(/** Request info */)
      console.log(/** Headers, Body, Method, URL...*/)
      return method.call(this, ...args);
    }
  }
}
```

and try to use it on a controller method like this.

```
export class Controller {

  @Get('/path')
  @Tracking()
  public async getData(@Headers('user') user: User) {
    return this.service.getData(user.id);
  }
}
```

If this is impossible, is there a way to apply interceptor to some method of controller?
Or is there a thread(like)-level context for request?

Thanks!!

Comment: [you can bind interceptors to some method](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#binding-interceptors). No tsure about the second point but have you ever read about [injection scopes](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes)?

Comment: I think what you need is a middleware - https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware

Comment: @MicaelLevi Thanks, I missed that important line when I read the docs... well i think they should list all the usage in the example section which i pay the most attention onto...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decorators don't have access to the request information because of what a decorator is. It's a higher order function that is called to set metadata for the class, class member, class method, or class method parameter. This metadata can be read at runtime, but it is called and set essentially as soon the file is imported. Due to this, there's no way to call a decorator on each request, even Nest's `@Body()` and `@Req()` are called at the time of import and read at the time of the request (actually earlier but that's besides the point).

What you're looking for here sounds more like an interceptor, like Micael Levi and hoangdv have already mentioned. The Nest docs [show a basic logging example](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#aspect-interception), and there are packages out there like [@ogma/nestjs-module](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma) (disclaimer: I'm the author) that handle this request logging/tracking for you including the addition of correlation IDs.